# Login in a Browser with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, browser, login-script

I would like to write a tool that has the users account name and password for, say, Twitter. It then accesses his browser and logs him in – in the browser. So that he can then just use the browser, open Twitter and is already logged in.

How would I go about realising this in Objective-C? Which browser would be the easiest to realize this with?

[Twitter is just an example here]

Comment: Is Twitter just an example or you need an api to access a user's Twitter account?

Comment: Twitter is just an example. I want my tool to log in Twitter or Gmail or Facebook, within the Browser of the user.